# Where can I find good, free resources on differential equations?

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to know if there are any good online books, lecture notes, videos, tutorials, or similar that are free to the public (on differential equations).  Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I have converted the question to [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741), as it's asking for a big list and there is no single right answer.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles:  Thanks!

Comment: @Matt: What's your background? Are you talking about ODE or PED, or both? More information may be helpful for people to answer you questions.

Comment: My background is computer science.  I took a class on ODEs, but it's been awhile.  I'd like to start with ODEs, but really anything is good at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favorite one:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/

Answer (score 2):

Paul's online notes has a section on Differential equations:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DE.aspx.

I have not personally read them, but the rest of his notes are helpful and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

well this one gives you a very huge collection to choose from

http://library.nu/search?q=differential%20equations

It requires you to be a registered member.

Comment: well was that meant as sarcasm? anyhow, i have rephrased my words. if my previous answer seemed off the track, sry

Answer (score 1):

You could try my notes, which include ode and pde. There are also applets
on my web page.

http://www.math.cornell.edu/~bterrell/dn.pdf